# Why doesn't static route work here?

Tags: networking, routes

I am studying the course of CCNA all by myself, and I've been trying to set up a really simple network with only two hosts and two routers on Cisco Packet Tracer. The problem here is that I cannot ping router0 from laptop0 without using a dynamic routing protocol(I tried RIP, which proved successful, so there is no problem with the ip configuration...).

[image]

I tried configuring a static route on router1 with the following command:
router(config)#ip route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.2

and I also tried the default route command:
router(config)#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.10.2

Both of these two commands proved useless.

Please kindly advise me what is the problem here...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You will need to configure static routes on both devices. Try this configuration:

on 192.168.10.1
ip route 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.2

on 192.168.10.2
ip route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1

Also notice you shouldn't need to configure routes to the directly connected networks. When you configure the ip address and subnet on that it should add a connected route.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sir, really helpful, I forgot the Ping command is somewhat a "two-way" street. :-)

Comment: But... if I do not configure the directly connected route, that is, if I do not use RIP or static route command like above, I would not be able to ping router0 from host0, is it a problem with the software Cisco Packet Tracer?

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused with what you are saying. So for the directly connected routes when you do interface XXX ip address YYY that should add a connected route for the given network. If yo do show ip routes you should be able to see these routes.

Comment: yes, the route should have been added right after I configured the ip addresses of the interfaces of all devices. For example, _show ip route_ on router1 produces the following results: 


`C    192.168.10.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
C    192.168.20.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1`

and _show ip route_ on router0 produces:

`C    192.168.10.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
C    192.168.30.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1`


hmmm, should I add "192.168.0.20/24" to router0? !

Comment: The problem is solved, thank you so much for your answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

firstly i aggre with David Mokon Bond for his answer. You can use also this way for default routing: 
on router 1: ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.10.2
on router 0: ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.10.1